# libcurand.so.9.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: cuda

I just installed cuda.9.2 following the instruction [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/799184/how-can-i-install-cuda-on-ubuntu-16-04). However, running my program using GPU produces an error.

```
error while loading shared libraries: libcurand.so.9.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

simon@desktop:/usr/local/cuda/lib64$ ls libcurand.so.9.2
libcurand.so.9.2
simon@desktop:/usr/local/cuda/lib64$ ls -lh libcurand.so.9.2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Jul 31 11:35 libcurand.so.9.2 -> libcurand.so.9.2.148
```

I notice there are a few reports on similar issues already. Does anyone have any idea on how to solve it?

Comment: Try executing the following command before running the program:  `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64 && sudo ldconfig`.

Comment: Follow the instructions in [the CUDA linux install guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html).  Especially note section 7,

Comment: @RobertCrovella This should be the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following sgarizvi's suggestion works. Indeed I forgot to export the path.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64 && sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: Having same issue but I don't have cuda.. (gpu)! How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Sound stupid, but using conda I solved it  `conda install cudatoolkit`